# How to use Google Speech to Text api in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-speech

I would like to use google api speech to text in my Xamarin forms App.

What I would like :

```
1.Load an audio(.wav) file in my Xamarin forms  App  
 -The audio file in the app is in : MyApp => Data => Audio.wav

2 Where to put my credential in the code 

3 Have texte string output from my audio
```

Here is the code that I have succed to do in Google cloud platform but I cannot see how to do the same in Xamarin form on visual studio :

I have found this the code from this link [click here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-speech-text-csharp/index.html?index=..%2F..index#5):

```
using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1;
using System;

namespace SpeechToTextApiDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
            var config = new RecognitionConfig
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Flac,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = LanguageCodes.English.UnitedStates
            };
            var audio = RecognitionAudio.FromStorageUri("gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac");         

            var response = speech.Recognize(config, audio);

            foreach (var result in response.Results)
            {
                foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/94534/how-to-use-google-cloud-speech-api-within-xamarin-forms

Comment: Please take a this simple:https://github.com/NateRickard/Xamarin.Cognitive.Speech